# Why does the sub surf modifier round off only one side?

Tags: modifiers

My subsurf modifier is only rounded on one side, anyone know why?

[image]

[image]

Comment: With the geometry selected in edit mode, type `SHIFT + N` to recalculate the normals

Comment: Amazing thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to 'Gorgious' for the answer!
"With the geometry selected in edit mode, type SHIFT + N to recalculate the normals"